# or condition not working with cucumber tags

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I am working on cucumber(4.1.0), ruby(2.3.3) and Rakefile. I have one basic feature to test how tags are working.
Following is the Feature having 3 different scenerio.

```
Feature: Test::Unit
  In order to please people who like Test::Unit
  As a Cucumber user
  I want to be able to use assert* in my step definitions
  

 @smoke
  Scenario: assert_equal
    Given x = 5
    And y = 5
    Then I can assert that x == y
    
  @online
  Scenario: assert_equal
    Given x = 6
    And y = 6
    Then I can assert that x == y
    
  @smoke @online
  Scenario: assert_equal
    Given x = 7
    And y = 7
    Then I can assert that x == y
```

and following is the Rakefile having three tasks.

```
require 'cucumber/rake/task'
namespace :cucumber do
    Cucumber::Rake::Task.new("smoke") do |t|
      tags = "--tags @smoke"
      t.cucumber_opts = "#{tags} -p online"
    end
    
    Cucumber::Rake::Task.new("online") do |t|
      tags = "--tags @online"
      t.cucumber_opts = "#{tags} -p online"
    end
    
    Cucumber::Rake::Task.new("smokeonline") do |t|
      tags = "--tags @smoke or @online"
      t.cucumber_opts = "#{tags}"
    end
end
```

In this file 2 profiles are working fine.
rake cucumber:smoke
rake cucumber:online

but third profile rake cucumber:smokeonline not working which has or condition with tags and prints following message on console.
I was expecting because of this or condition all three scenerio should be exected.

What I am missing here?

[image]

Comment: (1) Post the command which executes your cucumber. (2) What do you mean by _is not working_? (3) Don't post screenshots unnecessarily.

Comment: rake cucumber:smokeonline is the command and as it can be seen in screenshot it says no such file or directory. I was expected scenerio exected.

Comment: I can't copy and paste text from a screenshot. If you post your commands, do it as text, not screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/?lang=ruby#hooks)
You can only omit quotes if the expression is a single tag

> **Running a subset of scenarios**
>
> You can tell Cucumber to only run scenarios with a particular tag:
>
> ```
> # You can omit the quotes if the expression is a single tag
> cucumber --tags "@smoke and @fast"
> ```

So all you need to do is change

```
"--tags @smoke or @online"
```

To:

```
'--tags "@smoke or @online"'
```